# Jquery serialize and model bind multidimensional array

Tags: c#, jquery, multidimensional-array, model-binding

I'm trying to Model bind a multidimensional array using ajax through MVC.  My single Dimension array maps fine the only thing that doesn't map is the multidimensional.

I'm grabbing the data using this function

```
 var datas = $(this).find('tr:not(:has(th))').map(function (i, element) {
        var tmp = $(element).find('td:not(:has(div))').map(function (i, element) {
            return $(element).find('p').clone().children().remove().end().text()
        }).get()
        console.log(tmp);
        return [tmp];
    }).get();
```

I can see the data is turned into a multidimensional array in chrome output. 
This is the Ajax function pretty standard I set Traditional to true:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        Code: Code,
        Datas: Datas,
        Headers:Headers,
        Title: Title,
        FootNotes: FootNotes
    },
    traditional: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:53602/Building/StoreTableData/",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {
        $(ElementSelector).css('border', '4px solid Orange')

        $(ElementSelector).data('TableID', resp.ID);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(thrownError.toString())
        $(ElementSelector).css('border', '4px dashed orange')
     }
    });
```

Here is the Method stub for the C#:

```
public ActionResult StoreTableData( List<List<string>> Datas, string Code, string Title, List<string> Headers, List<string> FootNotes = null){}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or guidance on how to do this?

**Update** the request parameter seems sketchy I dont know how it would figure out how big the interior arrays are by default here is the raw data posted from

```
Request.Params["Datas"] = "1 to 25, 1, 26 to 50, 2, 51 to 75, 3, 76 to 100, 
4, 101 to 150, 5, 151 to 200, 6, 201 to 300, 7, 301 to 400, 8, 401 to 500, 
9, 501 to 1000, 2 percent of total, 1001 and over, 20, plus 1 for each 100, 
or fraction thereof, over 1000"
```

Comment: it's too many parameters passed to this function. you are not able to do this in stages?

Comment: what do you mean? 5 & 5 footnotes is defaulted to null in case they're arent any